# Populating an Access combobox excluding values already in DB

Tags: ms-access, combobox, populate

The purpose of this database is to assign "variable names" to different "tables". We are taking our data and making limited datasets, so I'm using Access to document the process. I have 3 tables:

- tbl_var - containing all variable information
- tbl_db - containing the names and characteristics of the limited datasets
- tbl_vardb - a linking table where a table ID and variable ID are associated

I have created a form to choose which variable to add to a specific dataset. It's very simple with two dropdown boxes. One box is the names of the datasets. The other box is the names of all the variables. The problem is that if I have already selected "sex" as a variable for the "demo" dataset, I do not want "sex" to pop up as an option for future variable drop down values. After all, it's already in the dataset, no reason to add it again. Since there is more than one dataset,  hard-coding a dataset name in a query isn't really working for me.

How do I populate the variable dropdown with values that are not already in a specific dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tables [tbl_var] ...

```
variableID  variableName
----------  ------------
         1  LastName    
         2  FirstName   
         3  Sex
```

... [tbl_db] ...

```
datasetID  datasetName
---------  -----------
        1  Demo       
        2  SomeOther
```

... and [tbl_vardb] ...

```
datasetID  variableID
---------  ----------
        1           3
```

... if I have a combo box named [cbxDataset] that gets its items from [tbl_db] then I can have another combo box named [cbxVariable] whose `Row Source` is

```
SELECT variableID, variableName 
FROM tbl_var 
WHERE variableID NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT variableID 
        FROM tbl_vardb 
        WHERE datasetID=[cbxDataset]
    );
```

The `After Update` event of the [cbxDataset] combo box ensures that the other combo box contains the relevant choices

```
Private Sub cbxDataset_AfterUpdate()
Me.cbxVariable.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to try this right now. Thank you so much for your clear answer! I will follow-up with the results.

Comment: If I bind '[cbxDataset]' to 'Dataset_ID' in [tbl_db], I can't see the names _and_ bind to the 'Dataset_ID'. So, I'm using a query that gets both the IDs and names (Get DS Names). My form source is [tbl_vardb]. As of right now, I'm seeing nothing in the [cbxVariable] combobox. I will attempt to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @Lauren re: ID vs. name in a combo box - Another very recent question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19408623/2144390) might be of interest.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the Variable combobox. My rowsource SQL for that is: 
`SELECT TBL_Var.Variable_ID, TBL_Var.VarName
FROM TBL_Var
WHERE (((TBL_Var.Variable_ID) Not In 
(SELECT TBL_DS_VAR.Variable_ID, TBL_DS_VAR.Dataset_ID  
FROM tbl_DS_VAR  
WHERE Dataset_ID = [cbxDataset] )));`

My Control is the Variable_ID in the TBL_DS_VAR and I'm binding to the 1st column, though only showing the 2nd with a 0;1" column width.

Comment: @Lauren You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/330242/ComboDemo.zip).

Comment: I will use that to guide me.